# How can I give different functionality to a button that was created in a map function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using .slice to display only one employee's information by clicking on a button, but since I'm mapping the button to each employee the functionality is exactly the same for each employee, and can't think of a way for each employee's button to perform .slice at the correct place.

```
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
      >
        <h2 ref={(_subtitle) => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>More Info</h2>
        <button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
        {employees.slice(0, 1).map(info => (
          <>
          <p>{info.firstName}</p>
          <p>{info.lastName}</p>
          <p>{info.email}</p>
          <p>{info.phone}</p>
          <p>{info.address.streetAddress}, {info.address.city} {info.address.state} {info.address.zipCode}</p>
          <p>{info.bio}</p>
          </>
        ))}
      </Modal>
```

Each employee appears in a table and has this More Info button. There are 10 employees and each button opens the modal and lists the info for the employee at .slice(0,1), but I need each button to open at the correct place, (i.e. .slice(1, -8) will always display the info for the second employee)

```
                    <td>
                        <button onClick={() => setEmployeeToUpdate(id)}>Update</button>
                        <button onClick={() => moreInfo(id)}>More Info</button>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteEmployee(id)}>Delete</button>        
                    </td>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to replace the `.slice(0, 1)` with `.slice(n, 1)` depending on the employee selected index `n`? IMHO when you click an element of the list instead of simply toggling the is open state you should keep track of the employee object or its id, so here you would simply use `employee` instead of `employees.slice(0, 1)` or you would do something like `employees.find(it => it.id === employeeId)`

Comment: I answered what I thought your question was. You'll likely get a better answer if you show what you mean by "each employee's button" and what you mean by the "correct place" to slice.

Comment: So by fiddling around with it I've been able to use .slice to manually get the right info to display, it's just a matter of having each button behave independently. Each employee on the table has an individual button, but each button does the same thing on click.

Comment: @GACy20
I've edited the post to hopefully be a little more clear, I'm trying to think of the best way to word my question and have it make sense

Comment: FYI: Doing `employees.slice(0,1)` is just making a copy of the element at index 0. You can access the same data by doing `employees[0]`.
If you're already doing `.map` on the array, you don't actually need to do either because it automatically runs for every element in the array.
So `{employees.slice(0, 1).map(info => (` is the same as `const info = employee[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the selected employee info into the modal? If so, you could track the selected employee in state and show the modal when one is selected. To close the modal simply clear the selection:

```
function EmployeeList ({employees}) {
   const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee] = useState();

   return (
     <>
        <ul>
          { employees.map(e => (
              <li key={e.id} onClick={() => setSelectedEmployee(e)}>
                {e.firstName}
              <li>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
        <Modal isOpen={selectedEmployee}>
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedEmployee(null)}>close</button>
          <p>{selectedEmployee?.firstName}</p>
          <p>{selectedEmployee?.lastName}</p>
          <p>{selectedEmployee?.email}</p>
        </Modal>
     </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Yea essentially I want each employee to have a more info button that on click opens the modal and shows their email, phone, address etc.

Comment: Messed around with the code a bit using this solution and it's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Ray gave a good answer for using state to share the data.

I would aim to place the map somewhere that allows using the data in both places rather than storing a copy in state.

```
employees.map(employee => <>
  <td>
      <button onClick={() => setEmployeeToUpdate(employee.id)}>Update</button>
      <button onClick={() => showModel()}>More Info</button>
      <button onClick={() => deleteEmployee(employee.id)}>Delete</button>        
  </td>
  <InfoModel info={employee}>
  </>
})
```